# Можно ли сказать «Испытать бурю чувств и эмоций» или это неграмотно?

Tags: стилистика

Можно ли сказать  «Испытать бурю чувств и эмоций» или это неграмотно - использовать слова синонимы с союзом «и»?
Заранее спасибо за ответ.

Comment: Вас интересует сочетаемость слов или корректность соединения их союзом "и"

Comment: И сочетаемость и корректность соединения союзом. Мне сказали, что вместе их употреблять некорректно, т.к. они обозначают одно и то же

Comment: Иван, вам каждый раз кто-то что-то говорит. Надо бы более полно его представлять позицию оппонентов: вразумительно, с ссылками на источники... Или уж не слушать их вовсе.

Answer (score 3):

Я не вижу причин запрещать такую конструкцию. Во-первых, чувства и эмоции - не полные синонимы (акценты разные - как минимум, первое, по мысли автора, может быть, например, более внутренним переживанием, второе - с явными внешними проявлениями), а во-вторых даже синонимичная тавтология не всегда плохо - 
надо смотреть контекст.

Ну а если исходить не из бытового понимания, а из научного, то это вообще разные вещи. 
Смотрите, например, тут.

http://www.psytalk.spb.ru/psyvopros/emotsii-i-chuvstva/